# MySQLdb on python3: No module named release

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

When i tried to connect to database using python code it shows the following error:

```
    TTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ponmani\Desktop\test.cgi", line 5, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Can anybody help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks everybody now i installed python 2.7.3 now it showing different error.See my edited post for error.

Comment: Reinstall the mysql module, don't just copy it.

Answer (score 3):

MySQLdb is not listed as a Python 3 module on PyPi, where did it come from?  Unfortunately you can't just copy modules from Python 2 to 3 and expect them to work first time.

Answer (score 2):

According to [PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python) as well as [the MySQLdb website](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) MySQLdb does not support Python 3.  Not sure how you managed to install it, but it won't work.

Comment: pymysql is a drop-in replacement, it's maintained, it's better-behaved, and it supports python 3 (at least ["experimentally"](http://code.google.com/p/pymysql/source/detail?r=25)). In short: use pymysql instead.

Comment: there's an unofficial release he is using http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: root: good find! How do you know that's what he's using. And are they just blindly packaging it for python 3.2 in the hope that it'll magically work someday?

Comment: @ Mu Mind -- because i posted the link before :), could be, but 3.1.3 version seems to work... haven't tried 3.2. Anyway, using pymysql seems like a viable solution...or swiching back to 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the most elegant method, but it will fix your initial problem:
Instead of `from release import...` write `from .release import...` (note the dot before the "release").

Answer (score 0):

check the version of your mysqldb module , MySQL-python-1.2.3.win32-py2.7.exe and MySQL-python-1.2.4.win32-py2.7.exe ,only one is you need,try 2 times

Answer (score 0):

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/UsingMySQL

```
pip install --user https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-1.1.6.tar.gz
```

Then, update your settings.py to use the oracle django backend, "mysql.connector.django":

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
         ...
```